# Scroll down to Form DIV area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time I add an item - I want to scroll down to **Add Item Form** form (`#form_additem`) - how can that be done?

Example of HTML Code:

```
<div class="item"> 1 </div>
<div class="item"> 2 </div>
<div class="item"> 3 </div>
<div class="item"> 4 </div>
<div id="form_additem"> 
  Add Item: <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#form_additem").offset().top + "px"});
```

but it scrolling at the bottom of the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the [`scrollTo` plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). Then, it's as easy as: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/rVgna/.

```
$.scrollTo("#form_additem");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. And maybe scrolling to the very bottom of the page is OK, if `#form_additem` is the last element before `</body>`.

Also you can animate scrollTo() function, suggested by pimvdb:

```
$.scrollTo("#form_additem", 1000);
```